# Microsoft equivalent of ld --relocatable (link into new, relocatable object file)

Tags: visual-studio, linker, object-files, cl

GNU `ld` has an option `-r` / `--relocatable` to link a number of object files into a new object file. Do the Microsoft tools have a similar feature, either in `link`, in `cl` or in some other tool?

I do *not* want to create an archive (because this file will be passed to a different linker which does not support archives). I also do *not* want to create a DLL.